# Failed to retrieve data for this request

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to explain the problem, but really do not know about this myself. So, asking for the help  of this community.

[image]

I get this error when I try to see my database.

I do not know much about this, I am just learning this, so if anyone know about this, please let me know.

I tried to check with SQL Server Authentication, but I do not know the password of sa :D

So, if any one knows about this, please let me know.

Thank You in advance

Comment: could you paste the error instead of screenshot?

Comment: This is the error dialog box I see when I expand the "Database"

Answer (score 0):

with SA rights,this will do:

```
USE master
    GO
    SELECT NAME,STATE_DESC FROM SYS.DATABASES 
    WHERE STATE_DESC='SUSPECT'
    GO
    USE master
    GO 
    ALTER DATABASE <db name> SET EMERGENCY
    GO
    DBCC CHECKDB (<db name>) 
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE <db name>SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
    GO
    DBCC CHECKDB (<db name>, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) 
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE <db name> SET MULTI_USER
    GO
```

Comment: but please contact your DBA first.

Comment: DBA as Database administrator?
This is a college project, and I have not encountered in a situation like this before.
I just have to write this query?
I cannot afford to lose my data, my project review is on monday. So, is there any way I can be sure to get all my data and access as before?

Comment: I gets this reply when I run this code: [link](http://s10.postimg.org/xd0p4o6bt/Screenshot.png)

Comment: Message:

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'IMMEDIATE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: replace <db name> with msdb

Comment: try this before running the script : EXEC sp_resetstatus msdb

Comment: It shows: Warning: You must recover this database prior to access.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6fce2d35-58db-4e18-81af-8b8987d65323/how-to-recover-msdb-database-from-suspect-mode?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Answer (score 0):

I exchanged the msdb log and data files with a similar project of mine, and restarted the mssqlserver service, and restarted the microsoft sql server management studio, and voila! It worked :)